# AssertJ: how can I make JsonNode comparison handle IntNode and LongNode as same?

Tags: java, jackson, assertj

I have a `JsonNode` which is built out of a `Map<String, Object>`:

```
Map<String, Object> actual = Map.of("test", 3L);
JsonNode actualNode = mapper.valueToTree(actual);
```

I would like to compare such node against an expected file, that I load as such:

```
String expected = "{\"test\": 3}";
JsonNode expectedNode = mapper.readTree(expected);
```

When I print these two nodes, I see that they are exactly the same:

```
>> System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(expectedNode));
>> System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(actualNode)); 

{
    "test": 3
}
```

However, when I compare the two nodes using `assert-j`, I get the following error:

```
Assertions.assertThat(actualNode).isEqualTo(expectedNode);

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
 <"{"test":3} (ObjectNode@7ef2d7a6)">
to be equal to:
 <"{"test":3} (ObjectNode@5dcbb60)">
but was not.
```

If I debug the `.isEqualTo` of the assertion, I see that the failure happens because:

- The `3` in the actual node is a `LongNode` (which I understand since the original map contains a `3L`)
- The `3` in the expected node though is an `IntNode`

So when the equality is tested, the `IntNode` is not even an `instanceof LongNode` and so the assertion fails.

However, I really don't control how the `Map` behind the actual node is built. What can I do to make the assertion work in this case?

Fully reproducible example:

```
Map<String, Object> actual = Map.of("test", 3L);
String expected = "{\"test\": 3}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode expectedNode = mapper.readTree(expected);
JsonNode actualNode = mapper.valueToTree(actual);
Assertions.assertThat(actualNode).isEqualTo(expectedNode);
```

P.s. I have currently fixed it by serializing and deserializing the node:

```
JsonNode newActualNode = mapper.readTree(mapper.writeValueAsString(actualNode));
```

... but I was looking for something cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because the jackson defaults to `int` when it can fit in the untyped value (i.e up to 32 bit). So the `assertj` (even the jupiter assertions) has correctly failed the assertion, because actual and expected are indeed two different types. This behaviour can be controlled by the `DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS` feature. The last sentence of the java doc of that property says this;

> Feature is disabled by default, meaning that "untyped" integral
> numbers will by default be deserialized using Integer if value fits.

You can simply enable it when you create the `ObjectMapper`

```
mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS);
```

The downside is jackson will create values in larger long type  unnecessarily.

Comment: I think this is my favorite solution!

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, AssertJ is behaving correctly in reporting that the nodes are not equal as one has a long child and the other has an int.

You wrote:

> When I print these two nodes, I see that they are exactly the same

Printing the nodes using `toString` proves that their `toString` methods produce the same result. That's not the same as them being exactly the same.

If what you are looking for is to validate the `toString` of the node then:

```
assertThat(actualNode).hasToString(expectedNode.toString());
```

Comment: That could have been one solution indeed, even though I preferred the one configuring directly the object mapper, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[JsonUnit](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit) with [AssertJ style](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit#assertj-integration) is probably the best option:

```
assertThatJson(actualNode).isEqualTo(expectedNode); // passes
```

However, I would have expected the [AssertJ recursive comparison](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison) to work as well:

```
assertThat(actualNode).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(expectedNode); // fails
```

but this is not the case.

I created [#2672](https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/issues/2672) to track this potential improvement.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't add another dependency unfortunately. Indeed, usingRecursiveComparison didn't work for me either but I think for the same reason (the instanceof check)

Comment: The recursive comparison should have a lenient type check by default, but it doesn't work in this case as Jackson types are not known to AssertJ. I've raised https://github.com/assertj/assertj-core/issues/2672 to evaluate this use case.